# Math equation to image

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, math

I'm developing an application for Windows Phone that are using different kinds of math problems, such as hard equations. The thing is that I want this app to be nice and cool and therefor It's obviously that you can't use the * (snowflake) as the multiplication symbol and you can't use the ^ (roof-top) as the exponent symbol. No, what I want is that I want to parse equations into cool images. I mean like this:

[image: Math equation parsed to image]

I know that there are several ways to parse math, including Latex, MathML and many more, I do also know that there are many javascript based strategies to create images like this, but I still haven't found one that are compatible with Windows Phone 7 based on C#. And I don't want to have anything server based, I want the conversion between equation to an image to be done in the client.

If you have any suggestions please leave a answer.

Comment: How are you storing the equation, currently?

Comment: I can store the equation however that are necessary, but for the moment acording to this model: (√(324)+√(324)+10)/2

Comment: First I would make classes to represent each type of operator, also having properties like IsImmediateValue and InnerExpression (for example: (`3^(-1) * 2) * x` will be: `* with (* with (^ with (3, - with (0 , 1)) , 2)) , x` - and from there it will be much easier to have an algorithm or some state-machine to create an image out of it. It is also logically better, because those things really are "beings" - classes, and also you can calculate things more easily if necessary.

Comment: It still feels like I haven't received any specific instructions or examples on how to make this working, just some thoughts. I guess this problem Isn't that familar and similar as I thought. But thanks for your help I do really apprectiate it.

Comment: It's just a start. We are all thinking with you.

Answer (score 1):

So the "*" becomes a "."? Not sure whether that's cooler or not but you still don't need an image generator, a nice font will do.

Comment: Seems like you still haven't understand what the problem is. I told you that I was going to handle hard equations. Which means that they obviously will have more complex math such as square root, logarithms and so on. So for example, I want the square root sign to be as a roof over the whole squard number which is imposible to do with fonts as far as I know.

Comment: @Parek But you still can do it with a nice font, and have small additions like the one you mentioned done manually after rendering the text (continue the roof to be longer, etc). No need to recreate the WHOLE thing from scratch.

Comment: @YoryeNathan If you do know any fonts that are ready do this with I would really appreciate if you would like to shard it with me.

Comment: @Parek Sure, you can have a look [here](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/tmmath/tmsampl.htm) (download link at bottom-right-ish). And I'm sure that with some more googling you can find other great ones. Also, you can make your own fonts to fit your exact needs. It isn't hard, really, just time-consuming.